# Read null as empty set in springdata-cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I use spring-data-cassandra, and have entity like this:

```
@Table("users")
public class User {

  @Column("permissions")
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.SET, typeArguments = {DataType.Name.TEXT})
  public Set<String> permissions = new HashSet<>(); 
}
```

In cassandra I have table `users` with field `permissions` of type `Set`. It works fine when I store some values in the set, but when I try to store empty set, it becomes `null` when I read such entity from the repository.

Is there a way to force spring-data-cassandra to change `null` to empty `HashSet`? Or can I somehow add custom reader for this specific property of the entity?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR;

That's Cassandra's default behavior to return `null` for empty Collection and Map-typed columns.

### Further Read

Cassandra returns `null` values for lists, sets, and maps, which do not contain any items. This is especially unfortunate when using classes with pre-initialized fields as seen in your question. There's an open ticket ([DATACASS-266 - Loading empty collection-typed properties overwrites pre-initialized fields](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-266)) in the issue tracker - as of now, without comments or votes.

We're not exactly sure whether it's a good idea to skip setting properties or apply some sort of defaulting when dealing with empty (`null`) collections as this raises follow-up questions what to do when:

- Creating an instance through constructor creation: A value is required in such case. For property access, we could omit to set the property, for constructor creation we must provide a value.
- The pre-initialized collection contains items but the one received from Cassandra is `null`.
- We assume, the change would be applied, what will happen with already existing code that assumes empty collections default to `null`.

A possibility to address this behavior could be configuration on `MappingCassandraConverter` or an extension point to override so users can apply their own empty collection behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to eliminate the null collections in my model objects as well, and while it may not be possible to do that at the Spring Data level currently (version 2.1.x), there are some options you can consider:

- Use property access for the field in question (i.e. use the annotation `@AccessType(PROPERTY)`), and in the setter method, set the field to an empty collection when the argument is `null`.
- Define a compatible (see below) constructor that sets the field to an empty collection when a `null` is provided (and if the model is mutable, you may still want to provide the setter as above).

There are some caveats to ensure Spring Data Cassandra uses the desired constructor (e.g. don't provide a no argument constructor), so it's critical to review the "Object Mapping Fundamentals" section of the reference guide (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.fundamentals).

Among the recommendations in that reference guide (as of version 2.1 at least) is to use an all argument constructor and make model objects immutable, which would work well with the constructor-based approach to handling nulls.  Though it does mean writing and maintaining the constructor to handle the nulls rather than relying on Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor`.

I have used the property access approach in one case, but not the constructor approach.  However I do intend go the constructor route when adding new or model classes (I'm a fan of immutable objects, and will explore that route even without any collection fields)

I believe Spring Data Cassandra 2.0 also added persistence lifecycle callbacks which is another possible option I suppose, but I ruled that out, mainly because the logic would not reside in the model class itself (as well as going against the recommendations from the creators of the framework)